# PHP HTML Word Doc not showing image generated via URL

Tags: php, html, ms-office, doc

I have a php script that generates a word document by creating it in HTML and outputting it to `.doc` when attaching static images from my website, the images load fine in Microsoft Word 03 and 2010. However when attempting to use a URL to generate an image (by parsing it a parameter) the image doesn't seem to load.

```
header('Content-type: application/ms-word');
header('Content-Disposition: attachement;filename="report.doc"');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
print($output);
```

Heres what I'm trying to do, I have a URL (website.com/signature.php?form=XXXX) where `XXX` is the form ID. The signature.php takes in the ID nunmber, locates the JSON stored on the server and generates an image from the JSON file, using this jquery plugin http://thomasjbradley.ca/lab/signature-to-image/

The signature/image converts fine and I see it when I test it against some examples, however when opening up the document in word, it doesn't show.

```
<img style="display: block;" alt = "" width="200" height="74" src = "http://myWebsite.net/signature.php?form=' . $results[$i]['id'] . '" />
```

That's what I have for my HTML.

EDIT:

In my signature.php I have the following:

```
  require("DB/DBConnection.php");
  require("signature-to-image.php");

  $formID = $_REQUEST['form'];
  $dbh = DBConnection::connection();
  $sql = "SELECT signature FROM forms where id = ?";
  $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql); 
  $stmt->bindValue(1, $formID, PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $stmt->execute();
  $result = $stmt->fetch();
  if ($result != null) {
    $img = sigJsonToImage($result['signature']);
    header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
    imagejpeg($img);
    imagedestroy($img);
  }
```

Comment: Is that the actual html that you're writing? or part of the PHP that writes the html?

Comment: @MarkBaker it is part of the php that writes the html. `$output .= <img style="display: block;" alt = "" width="200" height="74" src = "http://myWebsite.net/signature.php?form=' . $results[$i]['id'] . '" />` is what I have, along with a whole bunch of other text that I didn't add to the OP

Answer (score 0):

I'd imagine it's looking at the headers, and not seeing what it wants.

Within the `signature.php` script, directly before outputting the image, try adding:

```
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
```

... Replacing jpeg with whatever format the image is being output as.

Let me know if that works, and we can take it from there.

Comment: it's a jpeg file, however I have static hard coded images (a logo) used in the header for each page which shows just fine in Word